# Running Processes in the Background in Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle, process, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

**Can anybody explain how I can run a process in the background of my apex app while continuing to use the app**.

For example I want to run a long update from the frontend but it takes while, so instead of waiting for it to finish, I want to continue working while it runs in the background and when it is completed then I am notified.

Please note at all this is happening in the application, when I say continue to work, I mean continue to work in the application (frontend) and not the apex development section.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 2):

You would want to use a job to run the long running update or whatever code you need to run. A good example of how to set this up can be seen in [this article](https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/germancommunities/apexcommunity/tipp/2201/index-en.html).